# vagrant + chef setup trying to git clone into synced folder

Tags: git, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo

I have a synced folder in my vagrant setup

```
local.vm.synced_folder "../api", "/api"
```

and I want to be able to `git clone` another repository into this folder like this:

```
git "api" do
  destination "/api"
  repository "git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git"
  revision "development"
  checkout_branch "development"
  action :sync
end
```

but I get an error saying:

```
==> local: STDERR: fatal: could not create work tree dir '/api'.: File exists
```

tried using another empty but already created folder `/test` and this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the destination to `/api/<repo>`. Your current code is changing the target of the clone to `/api` (the equivalent of `git clone git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git /api`).

Comment: yeah, but this is exactly what I want to accomplish: `git clone git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git /api`

Comment: ok, never tried this before and didn't know that this isn't possible. at least not like this :(

Comment: I see.  This boils down to 1) can you clone a git repo into an existing directory and 2) can you prevent vagrant from creating the folder on the guest machine.  Both seem like a no.